# Why was my 'Be Best' Winter Bash knitting removed?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, winter-bash, specific-answer, winter-bash-2019

Earlier this month, I posted a [Winter Bash knitting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339905/369802) (10k only link) based on [the First Lady's Be Best campaign promoting well-being and online safety](https://www.whitehouse.gov/bebest/), containing the knitted text 'Be Best' in red/blue letters on a white background.

While I'm aware of the controversy surrounding current [the First Family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_family_of_the_United_States), I thought it was a nice addition in the spirit of the holidays, coming together and looking at common goals (with online safety and well-being having support in many places, including SE, I thought).

Alas, things didn't go as I'd hoped. A user with whom I've been friendly for years now was suspended for criticizing my drawing skills (rightly, as you can see in the answer below). And no, I don't know the trick of importing nice images to get the perfect knittings. Personally, I like the human touch. ;)

More recently, my answer was removed altogether without an explanatory comment. Please explain why it was removed.

Answer (score 7):

> While I'm aware of the controversy surrounding the First Family

Yes you are.

As were folks in the comments.

As were folks who flagged

As such - eh, there you go, you have your reason.

*Personally*, I had to ask around on what the logo was, and the context, and why folks would be offended by it. Certainly the comments do reflect a certain amount of controversy. While we try to take a light touch with winterbash knit sharing, this seemed somewhat... unfun and serious. And yeah, I'd say that that voting spread does reflect a certain level of controversy rather than fun.

I mean, I could have sat back and waited for the inevitable R/A flags, but this seemed to be a nicer, less painful way to handle things.

> A user with whom I've been friendly for years now was suspended for criticizing my drawing skills (rightly, as you can see in the answer below)

While we don't discuss suspension reasons, if it makes you feel better, it wasn't for criticizing your drawing skills. Mine are *pretty* terrible too. You might want to discuss the reasons with the user if they're open to it, rather than putting down your own drawing skills and the horrible potential aftermath.